# glGetAttribLocation returns -1, why?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a barebones glut initialiser within which I create a OpenGL program and attach a couple of shaders to it. Everything works up to the point where I attempt to create an attribute. Simply put - `glGetAttribLocation` returns `-1`.

There's not much to read on the web as to a probably cause for this value.

```
    // Window.h
    GLuint glutProgram;
    GLint glutCoordinateAttribute;

    // Window.cpp
    window.glutProgram = glCreateProgram();
    // Shaders
    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    // Vertex shader
    const char *vsSource =
        "#version 120\n"
        "attribute vec2 coord2d;\n"
        "void main(void) {\n"
        "    gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "};";
    // Fragment shader
    const char *fsSource =
        "#version 120\n"
        "void main(void) {\n"
        "    gl_FragColor[0] = 0.2;\n"
        "    gl_FragColor[1] = 0.2;\n"
        "    gl_FragColor[2] = 0.2;\n"
        "};";

    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vsSource, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fsSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);
    glCompileShader(fs);
    GLint compileError = GL_FALSE;
    glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileError);
    glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileError);

    // Link resources
    glAttachShader(window.glutProgram, vs);
    glAttachShader(window.glutProgram, fs);
    glLinkProgram(window.glutProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(window.glutProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkError);
    glGetProgramiv(window.glutProgram, GL_ATTACHED_SHADERS, &linkError);

    const char *name = "coord2d";
    std::cout << "window.glutCoordinateAttribute: " << window.glutCoordinateAttribute << std::endl;
    window.glutCoordinateAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(window.glutProgram, name);
    std::cout << "window.glutCoordinateAttribute: " << window.glutCoordinateAttribute << std::endl;
```

The following programs when executed prints:

```
window.glutCoordinateAttribute: 0
window.glutCoordinateAttribute: -1
```

Comment: I would start with checking error-state of state machine after every operation. something like: `if(glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR){fprint(stderr,"Error on line %d\n",__LINE__);}`

Comment: Do you check compileError and linkError?

Comment: -1 means that the compiler decided that the attribute isn't used or compiling the program failed, you also never check the `compileError` or `linkError` flags

Comment: I did check compilerError and linkError, both are zero. I also checked glGetError() after each function call, nothing.

Comment: See previous comment. It's probably because `compiler decided that the attribute isn't used`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat why would the compiler do that (judging from the shader code I provide)?

Comment: Now `name` is defined?

Comment: @MorganWilde: "I did check compilerError and linkError, both are zero.". Note that thoes values are to be interpreted as booleans, zero means `GL_FALSE`, so it did not compile/link at all.

Comment: @derhass thanks so much! I totally misinterpreted the return value. I've posted my solution as an answer bellow, but if you would care to post this comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment @derhass posted, I found the issue. I was reading the return value of my shader compile status wrong. It turns out they were not compiling and as a result the compiler couldn't find my named attribute.

The problem with my shader code was an extra `;` after the `main` block.

```
    const char *vsSource =
    "#version 120\n"
    "attribute vec2 coord2d;\n"
    "void main(void) {\n"
    "    gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    "};"; // <- this is the problem
```

Removing it from within the quotation marks finally got the shader to compile. I don't have a clue as to why that semicolon mattered there, because most languages ignore empty statements.

This is the final working version for one of the two shaders.

```
    const char *vsSource =
    "#version 120\n"
    "attribute vec2 coord2d;\n"
    "void main(void) {\n"
    "    gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    "}";
```